# difference protobuf & non-protobuf methods

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I want to understand the difference between protobuf & non-protobuf methods with respect to grpc with some example

understand the difference between protobuf & non-protobuf methods with respect to grpc with some example

Comment: I suggest taking a look at https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/ for grpc usage with protobuf and at https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-with-json/ for grpc usage without protobuf. And then updating your question with more specific questions that you might still have.

Comment: Also https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/quickstart/ for grpc-java with protobuf.